# Dynamic sized labels inside a table not refreshing in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

My table has cells which have several labels. I want one of these labels to fit its size so text begins right below the Title (remember that Labels align text vertically unless you fit its container).

[image: My cell]

Problem is, the very first time the table is loaded all labels' texts are succesfully populated but label sizes don't actually graphically apply until the NEXT time a refresh is asked. (if I ask for a reloadData with the exact same information, the labels' sizes work flawlessly).

This is some of my cellForRowAtIndexPath code:

```
cell.body.text = user.message;
[cell.body sizeToFit];
```

The only solution I've found so far is double calling `[table reloadData]` but this is an ugly solution. Any way I can fix this?

Edit: Previous code was a summary, I'll show the whole code here as requested:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TwitterTweetCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TwitterTweetCell"];

    // Populate cell

    TweetModelData *tweet = [self.twitterModelData.tweets objectAtIndex:[indexPath item]];

    cell.tweetName.text = tweet.user;
    cell.tweetChannel.text = tweet.userName;

    cell.tweetBody.text = tweet.message;
    [cell.tweetBody sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}
```

Regarding cell size, everything is working ok. Depending on the size of the message each cell has a different size which was pre-calculated before.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ((TweetModelData *)[self.twitterModelData.tweets objectAtIndex:[indexPath item]]).tweetHeight + 30.0f;
}
```

Comment: show your complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code (means that label creation and assigning values).

Comment: @Erik full code added

Comment: you have to set height of the cell row using  this method: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
of tableview

Comment: @DhavalBhadania yes, I alread had it implemented, cell size is working ok. I added it anyways, thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it. Don't know the reason, but it seems disabling "Use autolayout" on my storyboard fixed it.

I'm guessing auto-layout was overwriting the layout changes I was applying so they had no effect until the next data reload.